# string in dictionary to dictionary

Tags: javascript

i am having a string in form of dictionary in the following way:`var str1= '{ "T1" : "1"},{ "T1" : "2"}, { "T2" : "3"},{ "T2" : "4"}, { "T2" : "5"}, { "T3" : "6"}, { "T3" : "7"},{ "T3" : "8"},{ "T2" : "9"}, { "T2" : "10"}, { "T1" : "11"}, { "T1" : "12"}';`

Plz give any idea how to convert it such that It behave as a tree like structure. i.e. T1 will search till next T1 in loop and will append T1 and its value in the current iterated term and similar to T2 and so on.. example str2.

```
str2='{ "T1" : "1"} ,{ "T1" : "2", "T2" : "3"},{ "T1" :"2", "T2" : "4"}, { "T1" : "2", "T2" : "5", "T3" : "6"}, { "T1" : "2", "T2" : "5", "T3" : "7"},{ "T1" : "2", "T2" : "5", "T3" : "8"}, 
{ "T1" : "2", "T2" : "9"},{ "T1" : "2", "T2" : "10"}, { "T1" : "11"}, { "T1" : "12"}';
```

Comment: First, wrap it into square brackets and parse with JSON.parse. Then loop the resulting array of objects and build your tree.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have a structure like this. It's not a valid JSON, you can't parse it as is, because you can't have the same property twice. So, what you need it's "normalize" it a bit, or get the values out of it in another way. For example:

```
var str = '{ "T1" : "1"},{ "T1" : "2"}, { "T2" : "3"},{ "T2" : "4"}, { "T2" : "5"}, { "T3" : "6"}, { "T3" : "7"},{ "T3" : "8"},{ "T2" : "9"}, { "T2" : "10"}, { "T1" : "11"}, { "T1" : "12"}';

var re = /"([^"]*)"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"/g;
var dict = {};

for (var matches; matches = re.exec(str);){  
  var key = matches[1];
  (dict[key] || (dict[key] = [])).push(matches[2]);
}
```

That will creates a `dict` object like:

```
{T1:["1", "2", "11", "12"], T2:["3", "4", "5", "9", "10"], T3:["6", "7", "8"]}
```